# What makes code line jump to cursor when clicked in code from split view

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Ok so i have been having this problem for a months now and have been just dealing with it, but today it really fu-bared my code.

Using Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and .Net framework version 4.6.01586 installed) if I am in split view mode of an ASP.Net website and I click in the code section the code lines jump to the location below my cursor!

Example: Normal Code

```
<tr id="R1">
            <td id="R1C1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEntryDateTxt" runat="server" CssClass="tblLblTxt" Text="Entry Date:" Width="130px" />
            </td>
            <td id="R1C2">
                <asp:Label id="lblEntryDate" runat="server" class="tblTxbTxt" Width="100px" />
            </td>
            <td id="R1C3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmitByText" runat="server" CssClass="tblLblTxt" Text="Submitted By:" Width="100px" />
            </td>
            <td id="R1C4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmitBy" runat="server" CssClass="tblTxbTxt" Width="100px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Code Lines Moved:

```
            <tr id="R1">
            <td id="R1C1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEntryDateTxt" runat="server" CssClass="tblLblTxt" Text="Entry Date:" Width="130px" />
            </td>
            <td id="R1C2">

            </td><asp:Label id="lblEntryDate" runat="server" class="tblTxbTxt" Width="100px" />
            <td id="R1C3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmitByText" runat="server" CssClass="tblLblTxt" Text="Submitted By:" Width="100px" />
            </td>
            <td id="R1C4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubmitBy" runat="server" CssClass="tblTxbTxt" Width="100px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

If I click after the closing td tag for R1C2 notice that the asp label has moved to just after the closing td tag where I clicked.

This is really annoying and I can not figure for the life of me why or how this is happening.

Can anyone shed some light on this or point somewhere that shows how to fix this? I am sure I probably messed up a setting or something but i have no idea what.

Thanks in advance for ANY help!

Comment: Though I couldn't exactly call out but you may need to play around: Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML or HTML(Web Forms)

Comment: I looked through them again but nothing in there is relevant. I am just at a loss as to how I managed to mess this up.

Comment: Maybe you changed your code blocks a bit.  Maybe VS is just rectifying the code bocks? and by that I mean the way VS automatically indents your code after.. lets say an IF statement.